# Create-react-app: Invalid unicode escape in identifier on Safari iOS10

Tags: javascript, unicode, safari, create-react-app, ios10

I am having trouble getting a create-react-app 3.4.1 build running on iOS 10 safari. It runs fine in development (npm run), but after building it, accessing the site throws the following error in the console : `SyntaxError: Invalid unicode escape in identifier: '\u2160'.`  (bitwise or character)

This is triggered on this line in one of the chunk.js bundles created during build:

```
(this.webpackJsonpappname = this.webpackJsonpappname || []).push([[2], [function(e, t, r) {
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
    {
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "copyfiles": "^2.2.0",
    "del-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "jszip": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-pdf": "^4.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-haiku": "^0.1.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "renamer": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.01%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "iOS 10"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "iOS 10"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas how what the issue could be?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you really need the support on a small scale, you can use the dev server, even though that is not ideal in most scenarios.